# Take data from custom dialogbox textarea and add the values to Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a Google Sheets script to take an input of an address, parse it and write specific line to specific cells.

Here is my dialog box:

```
function doGet(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Enter Address for PO#" + PONum);
}
```

And here is the html code it's polling:

```
<script>
function parseA(){
var addA = Document.getElementById('addressA').value;
return addA
google.script.host.close()
}
</script>

<div>
<textarea id="addressA" name="textarea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Close" style="margin-top: 20px" onclick="parseA()" />
</div>
```

My problem is that I cannot seem pass that data on to Scripts. I tried assigning the `showModalDialog` function to a variable, but it does not call the dialogbox at all then. I am quite stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this.   Basically you need to run the google.script.run.(variable)  to get information back to the .gs file so it can be inputed into a spreadsheet.

Html

```
 <div>
    <textarea id="addressA" name="addressA" rows="10" cols="50">sdf</textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Close" style="margin-top: 20px" onclick="parseA()" />
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
    function parseA(){
   var addA = $('#addressA').val();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(close).addData(addA);

    }

    function close(){
      google.script.host.close();
    }
    </script>
```

.gs

```
function doGet(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Enter Address for PO#" + PONum);
}

function addData(data){
Logger.log(data);
}
```

Comment: I am assuming the dialog is supposed to close with success, however it does not. Do you have any idea why it wouldn't?

Comment: I put it in there without testing.   Try replacing google.script.host.close() with a function name that all it does is run the google.script.host.close().

Comment: Nothing changes. The data isn't logged either.

Comment: Not sure why, but getElementById was not working.  I changed to using jQuery and it grabbed the input as expected.